# how to get string from xmlhttp.send(str) via POST in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, http

My code looks like that:
Client side JavaScript:

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST",url + page,true);
xmlhttp.send(str);
```

I'm missing the code to in PHP side to extract this string, which I assume is in the http post body.

Is it possible to send string array or is this method is restricted for xmls and strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send any data you like.

Usually, you would encode the data as *application/x-www-form-urlencoded*:

```
var data = "foo=" + encodeURIComponent(data) + "&bar=" + encodeURIComponent(more_data);
xmlhttp.send(data);
```

And then access it via `$_POST['foo']` and `$_POST['bar']`.

If you want to access the **raw** data, then you can access it via `file_get_contents('php://input');`

Use [`setRequestHeader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/nsIXMLHttpRequest#setRequestHeader%28%29) to specify the content type of the data you are sending.

Comment: Am I missing something? i'm building it like that var str = "user=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("user").innerText) + "&pwd=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("passowrd").innerText); and I get noting

Comment: What happens if you alert the string before sending it? What does your browser's Net tab show is being sent to the server? How are you trying to read it on the server? Are any error messages appear ing in the JS console?

Comment: I managed to do alert the mistake was in password ID, but I see only user=&pwd

Comment: Possibly are you trying to get the value of form controls rather then the inner text of an element that has actual content.

Comment: <input onfocus="resetColor('userID')" type="text" id="user" name="user1"><input onfocus="resetColor('passwordID1')" type="password" id="password" name="password1">

Comment: Yeah, `innerText` would give you `<input> this content if it was valid, which it isn't </input>`. You want the value.

Comment: Okay the solution was to use value instead of innerText. Still when I I try to echo from php file: echo $_POST['user'] I get this long output of strange xml <br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-
.....

Comment: Well I think it is important to say that you need to add to the header the following otherwise it wouldn't work. xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

Answer (score 0):

As  Canttouchit said, these headers must be send for any POST request:

```
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); // for POST escaped 'form' data
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", post_str.length);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
```